# Having NotSerializableException when managing a JavaRDD<Row> - Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I'm extracting data from a Cassandra db. I get a `ResultSet` correctly, then I turn it into a `JavaRDD<Row>` and that's fine too, but when I do the `mapToPair` on the `JavaRDD<Row>` in order to get a `JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>`, I get this error:

> [2017-06-20 13:59:53,038] ERROR Exception encountered (org.apache.spark.util.Utils:91)
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow

and so on.
Plus, when debugging, I get a source not found message from the debug console.
This is my code:

```
ResultSet rs = cm.getTweetsWithTime(topic.getText(), oraInizio.getText(), oraFine.getText());
JavaRDD<Row> queryResults = jsc.parallelize(rs.all());
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> popTweets = queryResults.mapToPair(x->new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x.getString("text"), (x.getInt("likecount")+x.getInt("retweetcount"))));
```

Full stacktrace:

```
> [2017-06-20 15:35:48,488] ERROR Exception encountered (org.apache.spark.util.Utils:91)
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.writeObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$.serializeWithDependencies(Task.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:432)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$3.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I get through this error?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: I did, check the edit. Thanks for your time. @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: What does `rs.all()` return?

Comment: It returns an empty list (weird fact. If I run the query in its class it returns a full size list)

Comment: Who's producing the `ArrayBackedRow` type instance?

Comment: `JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> popTweets = queryResults.mapToPair(x->new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x.getString("text"), (x.getInt("likecount")+x.getInt("retweetcount"))));` this line

Comment: So the `x` inside the lambda is of type `ArrayBackedRow`? If that type isn't serializable, you can't use it inside `parallelize`.

Comment: no, it has to be a com.datastax.driver.core.Row, so not a ArrayBackedRow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147174/discussion-between-sirdan-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the map function of Resultset and map it to a case class. It worked in my scala code.

```
 case class DataModelBean(i:Integer)
 val mapped = rs.map(f => DataModelBean(f.getInt("id")))
```